# How can I dump my c-indent-style in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, indentation

I am heavily playing with c-indent-style using the `c-set-offset` command. How can I dump the current c-indent-style please? I want to update then my init.el file.

It seems the value in `c-style-alist` does not contain the modification I've just made.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to `c-offsets-alist`

Values will be updated there (variable is buffer local)